# Where should I add contrib and non-free in Debian Bookworm?

Tags: debian, apt

I had this `Dockerfile` in which I wanted to install `translate-shell` and for that reason I had to add the `contrib non-free` to the end of source lines in `/etc/apt/source.list`.

```
FROM node:lts-bookworm-slim

RUN sed -r -i 's/^deb(.*)$/deb\1 contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt update \
    && apt upgrade \
    && apt install bc -y \
    && apt install git -y \
    && apt install -y procps \
    && apt install curl -y \
    && apt install inotify-tools -y \
    && apt install jo -y \
    && apt install jq -y \
    && apt install --upgrade unzip -y \
    && apt install gettext-base \
    && apt install bsdmainutils -y \
    && apt install translate-shell -y \
    && npm install --location=global npm -y \
    && npm install --location=global serve \
    && npm install -g npm-check \
    && cd /usr/local/bin \
    && curl https://getmic.ro | bash

RUN echo DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536 > /etc/systemd/system.conf
RUN echo DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536 > /etc/systemd/user.conf

RUN rm -rf package-lock.json \
    && npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

I changed the `node:lts-bullseye-slim` to `node:lts-bookworm-slim` and now I get this error:

> sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory

I can't remove that line, because in that case I get this error:

> E: Package 'translate-shell' has no installation candidate

So, I'm stuck at this point. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the “Components” entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources`:

```
sed -i 's/^Components: main$/& contrib non-free/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources
```